# Ansible: Can I force include: to use another path

Tags: ansible

I have the following problem.  I'm keeping two separate Ansible project directories for two different technologies.  Imagine you have a nice Ansible setup and want to pull an Ansible project and use some of your established structure without integrating it completely.

The first statement does what I want.  It gives a fq path.

- `debug: msg="{{lynx_ansible}}/roles/centos_common/centos_{{jdk_provider}}.yml"`
- `include: "{{lynx_ansible}}/roles/centos_common/centos_{{jdk_provider}}.yml"`

The include adds a path to the ansible-project root dir and doesn't expand the variables.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try `$lynx_ansible` rather than `{{ lynx_ansible }}`. Include doesn't seem to support jinja2 syntax.

Comment: Does this work for you?  I don't get any expansion with $lynx_ansible.  It just tacks it on like /path/to/playbook/$lynx_ansible/roles/tasks/main.yml

Comment: With the doc reorganizing, i can't find it, but there was a section that states that includes did not allow for variable subs, although now that role dependencies do, perhaps they will for consistency.

Comment: Hm, this is odd, I tried with {{ }} syntax before and it didn't work for me, but both {{ }} and $ are working fine for me in includes, under Ansible 1.3.2. Which version are you using?

Comment: i'll try and post a gist.